# universal inner product of pandas.Series AND columns in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a function that computes the conditional Shannon entropy in a dataframe. I give it the following parameters:

```
import random
rows = 1000
columns = 3

data=pd.DataFrame([[random.randrange(0, 4, 1) for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
target = ['a', 'b']
conditional = ['c']
```

so in this example I will be simultaneously computing H(a|c) and H(b|c). Here's the code:

```
""" Split the data into groups according to 'c', then
    compute the shannon entropy for each column within each group """

entropy =  data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(shannon)
print("Entropy type", type(entropy), "\n",entropy.head(), "\n")

""" Then compute a Series with the probability of each value of 'c' """
prob_condition = data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(len)/len(data)
print("Prob type", type(prob_condition), "\n",prob_condition.head(), "\n")

""" Different ways to compute the mean entropy, weighted 
    by the probability of each occurrence in 'c' """
print(entropy.apply((lambda x: (x * prob_condition))))
print(entropy.apply(lambda x: prob_condition.dot(x)).head(),"\n")
```

which generates the output:

```
    Entropy type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
           a         b
c                    
0  1.992605  1.984517
1  1.987800  1.980181
2  1.979485  1.994622
3  1.990220  1.982847 

Prob type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
 c
0    0.251
1    0.248
2    0.264
3    0.237
dtype: float64 

Method 1: 
 a    1.987384
b    1.985713
dtype: float64 

Method 2: 
 a    1.987384
b    1.985713
dtype: float64
```

Now, if my target is just `'a'`, then I run into trouble:

```
target = ['a']
```

The output being:

```
Entropy type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
 c
0    1.992605
1    1.987800
2    1.979485
3    1.990220
dtype: float64 

Prob type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
 c
0    0.251
1    0.248
2    0.264
3    0.237
dtype: float64 

Method 1: 
 c
0    1.992605
1    1.987800
2    1.979485
3    1.990220
dtype: float64 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-100-d48372bac628>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('..../snippet.py', wdir='....')

  File "..../anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "..../anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "..../snippet.py", line 21, in <module>
    print("Method 2: \n", entropy.apply(lambda x: prob_condition.dot(x)).head(),"\n")

  File "..../anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2237, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63043)

  File "..../snippet.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    print("Method 2: \n", entropy.apply(lambda x: prob_condition.dot(x)).head(),"\n")

  File "..../anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1451, in dot
    if lvals.shape[0] != rvals.shape[0]:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The first method doesn't give me the right answer because I understand that `x * prob_condition` computes the outer product of the two vectors, and I need the inner product. On the other hand, the `.dot` function miserably fails, even I'm feeding it two Series...

I'm looking for a way to compute the inner product of each column in `entropy` and the Series `prob_conditional`, which should work regardless whether `entropy` is a Series (1 column) or a DataFrame (many columns).

PS: you may ask why don't I just do H(a|c)=H(ac)-H(c). The reason is that I want to time it, and I still haven't coded "joint" entropies. Also, I wouldn't learn what you are about to teach me :)

** Edit:** I add the whole shannon function so that the code is runnable:

```
def shannon(data, conditional=None, target=None):
    """ if no target is specified, try to guess it """
    target = [target] if type(target)==str else target
    conditional = [conditional] if type(conditional)==str else conditional

    if target==None and type(data)!=pd.core.series.Series:
        target=list(set(data.keys())) if conditional == None else [var for var in list(set(data.keys())) if var not in conditional]

    """ if there are conditions, split data in groups and apply independently """
    if conditional!=None:
        entropy =  data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(shannon)
        print("Entropy type", type(entropy), "\n",entropy.head())
        prob_condition = data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(len)/len(data)
        print("Prob type", type(prob_condition), "\n",prob_condition.head())
        cond_entropy = entropy.apply((lambda x: (x * prob_condition)))
        print(entropy.apply(lambda x: prob_condition.dot(x)).head())
        print(entropy.apply(lambda x: sum(x * prob_condition)).head())
        return cond_entropy if len(cond_entropy)>1 else cond_entropy[0]


    """ if data is a series compute right away """
    if type(data)==pd.core.series.Series:
        prob=data.value_counts()
        prob=prob/prob.sum()
        entropy= - sum([ (p * np.log(p) / np.log(2.0) if p>0 else 0) for p in prob])  
        return entropy

    """ if there are no conditions but several columns, evaluate each column independently """
    entropy = data[target].apply(shannon,axis=0)
    return entropy if len(entropy)>1 else entropy[0]
```

Comment: Can you provide the `shannon` function (or say where you got it, if it's part of some library)?  Your examples can't be reproduced without that.

Comment: well, this code snippet is in fact a part of it... I'll add the whole function

Comment: Okay, that may be part of the problem.  Your `shannon` function is doing a lot of checking on whether it's operating on a Series or DataFrame.  Have you considered using `transform` rather than `apply`, so that your function will be called on each column (rather than the whole DataFrame)?  I think that will result in simpler handling, because you should always get a DataFrame back (with just a 1-column DataFrame if you just have one column in `target`).

Comment: I cannot apply transform on a DataFrame. Doesn't apply feed the columns individually?

Comment: Let me put it in a simpler way: your `shannon` function sometimes returns a Series and sometimes returns a DataFrame.  I think you should try to make your `shannon` function *always* return a DataFrame (just a one-column DataFrame if need be).  Then you won't have your problem about having to deal separately with Series and DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. Following @BrenBarn's advice I tracked the use of DataFrames and Series.

The problem I was having with the case `type(entropy)==Series`, (when there is just one column, `target=['a']`), is due to unexpected behavior of the `apply` function in line `entropy =  data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(shannon)`. When called on Groupby with just one column, `apply` returns a Series, whereas the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) states it will always return a DataFrame (not that it is very explicit on this, by the way). This was the problem, because then the subsequent `apply` call was feeding individual elements (single-column rows) to compute the inner product, which of course cannot be done.

I replaced the `Groupby.apply` call by a `Groupby.aggregate` call, which has the same behavior and returns a DataFrame regardless the number of columns. I have to say that I am a bit uneasy about the [lack of documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate) on the latter.

I post the entire function for the sake of completeness:

```
def shannon(data, conditional=None, target=None):
    """ if no target is specified, try to guess it """
    target = [target] if type(target)==str else target
    conditional = [conditional] if type(conditional)==str else conditional

    if target==None and type(data)!=pd.core.series.Series:
        target=list(set(data.keys())) if conditional == None else [var for var in list(set(data.keys())) if var not in conditional]

    """ if there are conditions, split data in groups and apply independently """
    if conditional!=None:
        entropy =  data.groupby(conditional)[target].aggregate(shannon)
        prob_condition = data.groupby(conditional)[target].apply(len)/len(data)
        cond_entropy = entropy.apply(lambda x: sum(prob_condition * x))
        return cond_entropy if len(cond_entropy)>1 else cond_entropy[0]


    """ if data is a series compute right away """
    if type(data)==pd.core.series.Series:
        prob=data.value_counts()
        prob=prob/prob.sum()
        entropy= - sum([ (p * np.log(p) / np.log(2.0) if p>0 else 0) for p in prob])  
        return entropy

    """ if there are no conditions but several columns, evaluate each column independently """
    entropy = data[target].apply(shannon,axis=0)
    return entropy if len(entropy)>1 else entropy[0]
```